# Can I create a Chrome extension that shows several pages in one window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'd like to show several webpages in one Chrome window by either writing an app or an extension.

Genuine iframes won't do, because some webpages either disable loading in iframes, or otherwise problems with content-security-policy directives prevent this from working.

`webview` tags don't use the browser's extension set, or write to history and so on - they seem to be just kind of little browsers of their own.

App Windows would be nice if instead of having their own window, they could be embedded in a single host window.

What I'd like is several "iframe-*like*" components that act completely like a normal Chrome viewport from the loaded site's perspective, and upon which installed extensions work, etc.  If I were able to install extensions inside a webview, that would work too.

Is there anything like this that I can use within a Chrome app or extension?

Comment: Nope, iframe/frame is the only such thing.

Comment: it is totally possible to use iframes and workarround both the iframing permissions and other permissions issues with a chrome extension by capturing and overwritting those events. google for it a bit

Comment: @ZigMandel I did Google a bit before hand, but I came to the conclusion that there are so many ways a page can detect if it's in an iframe and disable itself as a consequence, that unless the browser itself lies to the page you can't really guarantee that every page will work.

Comment: generally, pages do not check to see if they are on an iframe, they just rely on the cross-site permissions that the browser enforces, as told by the response headers, which you can catch and modify with an extension monitoring network requests.

Comment: As I say, for my use case it's not good enough that something *generally* work, it needs to *always* work.